# Xero "Projects" - assigning invoices to a project via API

Tags: xero-api

I need to be able to associate an ACCPAY to a Xero Project.

I understand that this is done at the line item level on the front end.

Ive been searching through the docs and cannot find anywhere refernce to it.

Has anyone been able to associate a ACCPAY line item to a xero project?

Looked a Xero Accounting API referenece for GET and POST ACCPAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to associate a project to an invoice (ACCPAY or ACCREC) through the API.

The project is a label in Xero rather than a field and so is not accessible from the API

Comment: Thanks for the response @sallyhornet - disappointing though :(
Im assuming there isn't a "Label" API?